# How can we get value by selectedOption from react-select npm package?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-select

I am getting array of value label pair in React-Select npm package but I want to get value in string format.Code is given below:-

```
handleChange = selectedOption => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
  };

Actual output:- Option selected:[{value:'Apple'   label:'Apple'},{value:'Banana'   label:'Bnanana'}]
Expected Output:- Option selected: Apple,Banana
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just map through the selected options:

```
handleChange = selectedOption => {

    const selectedOptionValues = selectedOption.map(({ value }) => value );
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOptionValues);
    this.setState({ selectedOption: selectedOptionValues });

};
```

Comment: I want to store selectedOptionValues in setstate but I am getting error.

Comment: Cannot read property 'map' of null and also my search box stop function properly.

Comment: @Sharadkumar - that means you're passing an incorrect `selectedOption` as an argument. Add more code to the question or create a stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **map**:

```js
const myArray = [{value:'Apple',label:'Apple'},{value:'Banana',label:'Bnanana'}];
let results = myArray.map(el => el.value);
console.log(`Option selected: ${results.toString()}`);
```